# how to remove single quotes(') in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

```
@content = "<p><span style=\"font-family: 'trebuchet ms', 'geneva'; font-size: 'large';\">Helo's</span></p>"
```

I want to remove single quotes (`'`) from `<style>` but not from the `Helo's`. Right now I'm using this but this remove all the single quotes(`'`).

```
@content.gsub(/'/,"")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
@content.gsub(/style=".+?"/){ |x| x.gsub("'", '') }
```

This would remove the single quotes from the style attributes.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are going to need to parse the HTML with something like [nokogiri](http://nokogiri.org/). Only then you will be able to replace the text content of the tags.